# ArrayList shared preference overwritten everytime I start a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an arraylist of string, MainActivity reads the string and then turns it into a Gson, the app then moves on to the next activity (history.class activity) and then prints out the arraylist by retrieving it. I've implemented a button which returns back to MainActivity but the arraylist will be overwritten everytime I return back to the MainActivity, is there a way to overcome this? Also, I do not want to use `close()`or `finish()` as  a way to return to the MainActivity.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ArrayList<String> arrPackage;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("USER",MODE_PRIVATE);
        final EditText address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        final TextView result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        Button save = findViewById(R.id.button);

        arrPackage = new ArrayList<>();
        final Intent next = new Intent(this,history.class);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(address.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Plz Enter all the data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    String addressData = address.getText().toString().trim();
                    arrPackage.add(addressData);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(arrPackage);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("Set",json );
                    editor.commit();
                }
                startActivity(next);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**History.class**

```
public class history extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        Button back = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        TextView result = findViewById(R.id.tv_history);
        final Intent back_activity = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("USER",MODE_PRIVATE);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Set", "");
        if (json.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(history.this,"There is something error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<String> arrPackageData = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for(String data:arrPackageData) {
                builder.append(data + "\n");
            }
            result.setText(builder.toString());

        }
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(back_activity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arrPackage = new ArrayList<>();
```

this line overrite your arrayList. to save you arrayList you need check first if there's data save in preference list as

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Set", "");

    if (json.isEmpty()) {
        // runs when you app dont have data in shared preference initalize your arrayList here
        arrPackage = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        // when your app already stored list then read from the preference.
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
        }.getType();
        arrPackage  = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

Comment: Where do I include the section of code that you've written, I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: arrPackage = new ArrayList<>(); replace with this

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in AndroidManifest.xml inside your Activity entry:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

For example :

```
<activity
        android:name="your_package.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

By this, your MainActivity will become single instance Activity and when you call startActivity for it, the already created Activity will come to the foreground.